# jQuery Tools Tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I have a link with a background image that uses the jQuery tooltip on a list. There are multiples of these on a page (for example 20). The first one works just fine but the remaining tooltips do not work. Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code (I am using NHAML as my viewengine):

```
%script{language="Javascript"}
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download_now").tooltip();
  });

%a{id="download_now"}
  %div{id="tooltip" class="tooltip"}
    -string bulletSep = "|";
    -string[] bulletList = job.Requirements.Split(bulletSep.ToCharArray(),
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    %ul
      -for (int i = 0; i < bulletList.Length; i++)
        %li =bulletList[i]
```

Comment: To be of any help, we'll need to see the HTML source and the script you are using to attach the tooltips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this question, [jQuery Tools Tooltip Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814387/jquery-tools-tooltip-issue)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the plugin, but without your code it is impossible to determine the issue. I have written a tooltip/hovertip jQuery plugin which supports full HTML contents (images, text with html markup, etc...) It can be found at the link below.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hovertiphtml