# jQuery Tools Tooltip Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I am using the jQuery tools tooltip on a page. When the user rollovers a link, I would like to show a ordered (or unordered) list on a image. The list is dynamic for each link. I can get it to work for the first link but all other links do not work.

Does anyone have a working example of multiple dynamic jQuery Tools Tooltips working on a page?

Please help!!

Comment: You are going to have to post some code, to see what is going wrong. I assume you are using the tooltip plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by following this example, http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/form.html.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can just put your unordered list right after your link.... [as the demos on the site say](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html):

> By default, this tool assumes that the
>   tooltip is placed right after the
>   trigger element.

So add as many as you like, but just make sure you put the tooltip (I think in a div) *immediately* after your link that you want to trigger it.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the demos on the site and I have read the documentation. I caa get it to work but it only works for the 1st one. Can you provide a simple example? Thanks.